# Unable to access multiple where case in where condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I try to access multiple where condition as stored procedure:

```
--EXEC RPT_LIST_BAK @Status='P/C,F,AT,CP'

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RPT_LIST_BAK]   
@STATUS         NVARCHAR(50)=NULL

AS
BEGIN

   set @STATUS = '''' + REPLACE(@STATUS,  ',', ''',''') + ''''

   SELECT   
            TotalFailed = COUNT(CASE WHEN DIV_REQ_COM_IND IN('F') THEN DIV_REQ_COM_IND END)
    FROM
      TWAD_DIV_MASTER A

    WHERE A.DIV_REQ_DEL_STATUS_ID = 1   
    AND A.DIV_REQ_COM_IND IN (@STATUS)
    GROUP BY A.DIV_REQ_MAT_ID
    ORDER BY A.DIV_REQ_MAT_ID  ASC

END
```

1. EXEC RPT_LIST_BAK @Status='P/C,F,AT,CP'
2. In select I get 'P/C','F','AT','CP' --  this s correct and also return value,
3. If I use "'P/C','F','AT','CP'" in where condition means it returns values
4. But if I use in where condition `(AND A.DIV_REQ_COM_IND IN (@STATUS))` it shows null value?

Comment: IN will always consider @Status as a single value. So what you are trying to get through your script A.DIV_REQ_COM_IND IN (@STATUS), you may go for Dynamic script execution.

Comment: How to make Dynamic script execution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with this below script? this should work.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RPT_LIST_BAK] @STATUS NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @QueryScript NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @STATUS = '''' + REPLACE(@STATUS, ',', ''',''') + '''';

    SET @QueryScript = '
    SELECT  TotalFailed = COUNT(CASE WHEN DIV_REQ_COM_IND IN(''F'') THEN DIV_REQ_COM_IND END)
    FROM TWAD_DIV_MASTER A
    WHERE A.DIV_REQ_DEL_STATUS_ID = 1   
    AND A.DIV_REQ_COM_IND IN (' + @STATUS + ')
    GROUP BY A.DIV_REQ_MAT_ID
    ORDER BY A.DIV_REQ_MAT_ID  ASC'

    EXEC (@QueryScript);
END;
```

Comment: WHERE A.DIV_REQ_DEL_STATUS_ID = 1 

AND A.DIV_REQ_STATUS_DATE BETWEEN COALESCE(' +CAST(@FROM_DATE as date)+ ', A.DIV_REQ_STATUS_DATE) AND COALESCE(' +CAST(@TO_DATE as date)+ ', A.DIV_REQ_STATUS_DATE)


If I try with a date means it shows Error

"The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator."

Comment: this will be something like ---- 'WHERE A.DIV_REQ_DEL_STATUS_ID = 1
      AND A.DIV_REQ_STATUS_DATE BETWEEN COALESCE(CAST('+@FROM_DATE+' as date), A.DIV_REQ_STATUS_DATE) 
   AND COALESCE(CAST('+@TO_DATE+' as date), A.DIV_REQ_STATUS_DATE)';